# Unknown custom element: <FullCalendar> - FullCalendar Vue

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to create a vue component that utilizes the FullCalendar vue component:

```
<script>
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/core'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'

export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar
  },
  data: function() {
    return { 
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events: '/schedule/month_events',
        eventOrder: "building_id",
        selectable: true,
        defaultAllDay: true,
        editable: true,   
        dateClick: this.handleDateClick,
        headerToolbar: {
          left: '',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'prev today next'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleDateClick: function(arg) {
      console.log('test');
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <FullCalendar :config="calendarOptions" />
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

and I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <FullCalendar> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

If I create my own component, it displays the template and finds the component just fine.

How do I properly use FullCalendar component in my Vue JS component?

Comment: If I look at the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue) you need to use `@fullcalendar/vue` you are using `@fullcalendar/core`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using **Vue** component, you need to import from `@fullcalendar/vue`. You are currently importing from `@fullcalendar/core`.

Comment: *slaps forehead* thanks, appears to have worked. New error now :)

Comment: Hi Harsal, please can you check my question? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67384812/full-calendar-styling-not-correct-after-import

Comment: Harshal, I'm going to post another question concerning adding events with the FullCalendar Vue component.