# Full Calendar Styling not Correct after import

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use React Full Calendar inside my project and though the calendar gets rendered in the correct way, the styling is a bit off. Here's how it is looking currently:

[image]

As you can see, in the header toolbar, the month word isn't aligned in the middle which is the same for other words and icons. Maybe, the size of the button itself is looking small in height.

The functionality of the button is working correctly but the styling isn't how it is that they are showing in documentation.

Here's the link to how it should actually look: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/toolbar-demo

Here's how I've included the FullCalendar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";

import "@fullcalendar/common/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css";
import "@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css";

class TimelineScheduler3 extends Component {

handleDateClick = (arg) => { // bind with an arrow function
 alert(arg.dateStr)
}

render() {



return (
  <FullCalendar
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin]}
    initialView="dayGridMonth"
    weekends={true}
    dateClick={this.handleDateClick}
    headerToolbar={{
      left: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear'
    }}
    events={
      [
        { title: 'event 1', date: '2021-05-05' },
        { title: 'event 2', date: '2021-05-07' }
      ]}
  />
)
}
}

  export default TimelineScheduler3;
```

Is some import missing from my end or is the styling of my application overriding styling of FullCalendar?

Comment: Can we modify the css inside of the node_modules? For example, inside @fullcalendar/common/main.css ? I actually tried manually changing that css but it wasn't getting reflected :(

Comment: I would expect your application is overriding the fullCalendar styles. The screenshot suggests it but the code you've provided doesn't prove it specifically.

Comment: @ShridharK There is a reasonably good chance that you default styling for button is causing this to happen. Also, modifying within node_modules is an *antipattern*. You must override using the classes that `FullCalendar` has provided or alter you application's default styling for button element. Also, if your calendar is within flexbox or grid, then also, this issue can happen.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @ADyson. For now, I've manually changed the style of Full Calendar by using this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177150/is-it-possible-customise-fullcalendar-with-css-in-react. As I couldn't understand how my application styling has overridden the Full Calendar styling.

Comment: Thanks @Harshal Patil for your input as well. Please check the above comment.